# Issue with accessing modules through PIP in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I use PIP to install the module for example

pip install [module name]

I go to python and write "import "
and get an error that says the module doesn't exist.

Comment: Can you elaborate on *where* you're using python? Are you doing this in a python console, or are you running a file? It's possible that you're installing into the wrong environment with pip, and then running python in a different environment.

Comment: This might be because the pip is different for different version of python unless you make it default.For python3 it would be pip3

Comment: ¿Are you using a virtual environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### PyCharm:

To manage Python packages for the project interpreter go to the project/settings inside PyCharm and choose Python Interpreter.
To install a package you click on + install package.
[Here it's better explained.](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/installing-uninstalling-and-upgrading-packages.html)

#### pip3

Sometimes, when we are trying to install some packages using pip and we have more than one version of Python, you have to specify:

If the package is to python3:

```
sudo pip3 install package_name
```

Comment: Apparently the typical way advised to install the modules wasn't aligned with my pycharm. Any idea what that is about?

Comment: I'm not sure, but maybe it's because of the way you installed pycharm. If you installed it using anaconda, you install packages to pycharm in a different way.

Comment: At any rate I have what I need worked out right now. Thank Ms. Cabistani for your time.